# font problem in firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts

i have some unusual problem in firefox, the font in firefox is not working properly, it become narrow then rest of the windows font, sometimes it looks very small, i have tried default settings of font in firefox, but it was not helpful, pleas if someone can help me it would be a great pleasure for me,,, i am giving a link to visualize the situation,

[image: ss]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might be missing a font-package. For example, in ubuntu-minimal, I do not have any extra packages so the terminal font overlaps each other. I used `sudo apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts` and that did the trick for the terminal. This may also work for firefox, if not, try other font families. These font packages can be found [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ttf-ubuntu-font-family)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have used the command, but the problem is still there, can you give me some other idea,